# Testing in FastAPI using Tortoise-ORM

Tags: python, python-3.8, fastapi, tortoise-orm

I'm trying to write some async tests in [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) using [Tortoise ORM](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) under **Python 3.8** but I keep getting the same errors (seen at the end). I've been trying to figure this out for the past few days but somehow all my recent efforts in creating tests have been unsuccessful.

I'm following the [fastapi docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-tests/) and [tortoise docs](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/fastapi.html) on this one.

**main.py**

```py
# UserPy is a pydantic model
@app.post('/testpost')
async def world(user: UserPy) -> UserPy:
    await User.create(**user.dict())
    # Just returns the user model
    return user
```

**simple_test.py**

```py
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from httpx import AsyncClient

@pytest.fixture
def client1():
    with TestClient(app) as tc:
        yield tc

@pytest.fixture
def client2():
    initializer(DATABASE_MODELS, DATABASE_URL)
    with TestClient(app) as tc:
        yield tc
    finalizer()

@pytest.fixture
def event_loop(client2):              # Been using client1 and client2 on this
    yield client2.task.get_loop()


# The test
@pytest.mark.asyncio
def test_testpost(client2, event_loop):
    name, age = ['sam', 99]
    data = json.dumps(dict(username=name, age=age))
    res = client2.post('/testpost', data=data)
    assert res.status_code == 200

    # Sample query
    async def getx(id):
        return await User.get(pk=id)
    x = event_loop.run_until_complete(getx(123))
    assert x.id == 123

    # end of code
```

My errors vary on whether I'm usinng `client1` or `client2`

Using `client1` error

```
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-9' coro=<TestClient.wait_shutdown() running at <my virtualenv path>/site-packages/starlette/testclient.py:487> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py:184]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

Using `client2` error

```
asyncpg.exceptions.ObjectInUseError: cannot drop the currently open database
```

Oh, I've also tried using `httpx.AsyncClient` but still no success (and more errors). Any ideas because I'm out of my own.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it surrendering to not using asyncio tests. Basically I have the same code as you, only the tests do not have the `@pytest.mark.asyncio` tag. In order to use `httpx` it may be worth to investigate the `event_loop` sharing, but for me it requires too much time and effort

Comment: Time and effort confirmed. I did try to look deeper into that event_loop and all it brought me was so much pain my ex would be jealous. So you dropped all form of async testing altogether? What did you do after?

Comment: I test synchronously the endpoints. The rest of the code is the same, but for the `asyncio` annotation on the test

Comment: Just found a similar issue [here](https://github.com/tortoise/tortoise-orm/issues/532) in the tortoise repo. It looks like this won't be going away anytime soon.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal runnable example? There is stuff missing (UserPy, initializer, finalizer) that makes it hard to reproduce this.

Comment: why do you mark `test_testpost` as async but it is not? Is that why you need another event loop? No need for either, just install the `pytest-asyncio` plugin

Answer (score 12):

It cost me about one hour to make the async test worked. Here is the example:
(*Python3.8+ is required*)

- conftest.py

```py
import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient
from tortoise import Tortoise

from main import app

DB_URL = "sqlite://:memory:"


async def init_db(db_url, create_db: bool = False, schemas: bool = False) -> None:
    """Initial database connection"""
    await Tortoise.init(
        db_url=db_url, modules={"models": ["models"]}, _create_db=create_db
    )
    if create_db:
        print(f"Database created! {db_url = }")
    if schemas:
        await Tortoise.generate_schemas()
        print("Success to generate schemas")


async def init(db_url: str = DB_URL):
    await init_db(db_url, True, True)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def anyio_backend():
    return "asyncio"


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def client():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as client:
        print("Client is ready")
        yield client


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
async def initialize_tests():
    await init()
    yield
    await Tortoise._drop_databases()
```

- settings.py

```py
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

DB_NAME = "async_test"
DB_URL = os.getenv(
    "APP_DB_URL", f"postgres://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/{DB_NAME}"
)

ALLOW_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "https://example.com",
]
```

- main.py

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from models.users import User, User_Pydantic, User_Pydantic_List, UserIn_Pydantic
from settings import ALLOW_ORIGINS, DB_URL
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=ALLOW_ORIGINS,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.post("/testpost", response_model=User_Pydantic)
async def world(user: UserIn_Pydantic):
    return await User.create(**user.dict())


@app.get("/users", response_model=User_Pydantic_List)
async def user_list():
    return await User.all()


register_tortoise(
    app,
    config={
        "connections": {"default": DB_URL},
        "apps": {"models": {"models": ["models"]}},
        "use_tz": True,
        "timezone": "Asia/Shanghai",
        "generate_schemas": True,
    },
)
```

- models/base.py

```py
from typing import List, Set, Tuple, Union

from tortoise import fields, models
from tortoise.queryset import Q, QuerySet


def reduce_query_filters(args: Tuple[Q, ...]) -> Set:
    fields = set()
    for q in args:
        fields |= set(q.filters)
        c: Union[List[Q], Tuple[Q, ...]] = q.children
        while c:
            _c: List[Q] = []
            for i in c:
                fields |= set(i.filters)
                _c += list(i.children)
            c = _c
    return fields


class AbsModel(models.Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    created_at = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True, description="Created At")
    updated_at = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now=True, description="Updated At")
    is_deleted = fields.BooleanField(default=False, description="Mark as Deleted")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ("-id",)

    @classmethod
    def filter(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> QuerySet:
        field = "is_deleted"
        if not args or (field not in reduce_query_filters(args)):
            kwargs.setdefault(field, False)
        return super().filter(*args, **kwargs)

    class PydanticMeta:
        exclude = ("created_at", "updated_at", "is_deleted")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__} {self.id}>"
```

- models/users.py

```py
from tortoise.contrib.pydantic import pydantic_model_creator, pydantic_queryset_creator

from .base import AbsModel, fields


class User(AbsModel):
    username = fields.CharField(60)
    age = fields.IntField()

    class Meta:
        table = "users"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


User_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User)
UserIn_Pydantic = pydantic_model_creator(User, name="UserIn", exclude_readonly=True)
User_Pydantic_List = pydantic_queryset_creator(User)
```

- `models/__init__.py`

```py
from .users import User  # NOQA: F401
```

- tests/test_users.py

```
import pytest
from httpx import AsyncClient
from models.users import User


@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_testpost(client: AsyncClient):
    name, age = ["sam", 99]
    assert await User.filter(username=name).count() == 0

    data = {"username": name, "age": age}
    response = await client.post("/testpost", json=data)
    assert response.json() == dict(data, id=1)
    assert response.status_code == 200

    response = await client.get("/users")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == [dict(data, id=1)]

    assert await User.filter(username=name).count() == 1
```

Source code of the demo had been post to github:
https://github.com/waketzheng/fastapi-tortoise-pytest-demo.git

Comment: it's working for me when i have only one model, but when i add new models i get error. `tortoise.exceptions.ConfigurationError: No app with name 'app' registered.` but aerich migrate and upgrade is working

Comment: @MojixCoder Could you show how to reproduct to error?